# Mock Abstract class using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the below abstract class and test method. Using "Moq" i got the below error:

My Abstact class :

```
   public abstract class UserProvider
{ 
    public abstract UserResponseObject CreateUser(UserRequestObject request, string userUrl);

    public abstract bool IsUserExist(UserRequestObject request, string userUrl);
}
```

Test Class :

```
  [TestMethod()]
    public void CreateUserTest()
    {
        var mockUserProvider = new Mock<UserProvider>(MockBehavior.Loose);

    //GetUserRequestObject is local method to set data

         mockUserProvider.
            Setup(u => u.CreateUser(GetUserRequestObject(), ""))
            .Returns(new UserResponseObject { uid = "123", uri = userUri }).Verifiable();

         var userProvider = mockUserProvider.Object.CreateUser(GetUserRequestObject(), "");

         mockUserProvider.Verify(u => u.CreateUser(GetUserRequestObject(), ""));
    }
```

Error Message :

> Moq.MockException:  Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but
>   was never performed: u => u.CreateUser(.GetUserRequestObject(), "")

Anyone please explain, why i got this message and how to resolve it?

Comment: What is the point of creating a mocked object, calling its mocked method, and verifying it was called?

Comment: I thought it's the way to test abstract class -> abstract methods. Creating mock object  -> setup method call -> verify. If any other way is there , please share it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you are getting this error, is because you are setting the expectation on a specific instance of an object:

```
mockUserProvider.Verify(u => u.CreateUser(GetUserRequestObject(), ""));
```

This will depend heavily on how the method is implemented. 
e.g. This implementation of `GetUserRequestObject()` will create a new instance on each call, and the verify will always fail:

```
  private UserRequestObject GetUserRequestObject()
  {
     return new UserRequestObject();
  }
```

Whereas returning the same instance for the setup and verify will succeed:

```
  private UserRequestObject u = new UserRequestObject();
  private UserRequestObject GetUserRequestObject()
  {
     return u;
  }
```

Instead of being dependent on an exact instance (i.e. avoid comparing 2 references), you could instead either check for *Any* instance:

```
mockUserProvider.Verify(u => u.CreateUser(It.IsAny<UserRequestObject>(),
                        It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
```

Or preferably, an instance which meets a specific criterion (Assuming that `GetUserRequestObject()` has a property `Name` which is set to `Bob`)

```
mockUserProvider.Verify(u => u.CreateUser(
                        It.Is<UserRequestObject>(x => x.Name == "Bob"),
                        It.Is<string>(s => s == "")));
```

Comment: I tried this line , it shows the below error

    mockUserProvider.Verify(u => It.Is<UserRequestObject>(u => u.uid == "123"));

Error 87 A local variable named 'u' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'u', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something

Comment: Apols - I had already used that variable name in the outer lambda. I've updated (replaced the inner 'u' with an 'x').

Comment: Thanks, but after changing the code i got the below message :
Test method CreateUserTest threw exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: u => It.Is<UserResponseObject>(x => x.uid == "123")
Result StackTrace: 
at Moq.Mock.ThrowIfVerifyNonVirtual(Expression verify, MethodInfo method)
   at Moq.Mock.Verify[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times)

Comment: i just realized why @kobi commented like that. I need to verify output of the createuser only.

Comment: Yes, you aren't really testing anything useful, other than Moq's ability to track called parameters :) But at least you are getting the idea of how to use it!

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetUserRequestObject()` might be returning 2 different instances of the `UserRequestObject` object.

Ensure the same instance is used for both setting the expectations and verifying it via the call. (else, use `It.IsAny<UserRequestObject>` while setting expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Moq checks the reference to your object. You should verify and pass to it the same object that you used in setup method:

```
public void CreateUserTest()
{
    var mockUserProvider = new Mock<UserProvider>(MockBehavior.Loose);

//GetUserRequestObject is local method to set data
     var user = GetUserRequestObject();

     mockUserProvider.
        Setup(u => u.CreateUser(user, ""))
        .Returns(new UserResponseObject { uid = "123", uri = userUri }).Verifiable();

     var userProvider = mockUserProvider.Object.CreateUser(user, "");

     mockUserProvider.Verify(u => u.CreateUser(user, ""));
}
```

Alternatively you may check it for any object passed to method:

```
public void CreateUserTest()
{
    var mockUserProvider = new Mock<UserProvider>(MockBehavior.Loose);

//GetUserRequestObject is local method to set data

     mockUserProvider.
        Setup(u => u.CreateUser(Is.Any<User>(), ""))
        .Returns(new UserResponseObject { uid = "123", uri = userUri }).Verifiable();

     var userProvider = mockUserProvider.Object.CreateUser(Is.Any<User>(), "");

     mockUserProvider.Verify(u => u.CreateUser(Is.Any<User>(), ""));
}
```

Comment: This is working as expected, given +1. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

very simply - you are doing everything right but your verify is wrong.

you are creating a new user provider but have not specified that one will be created.

you need to use this rather than blanks:

```
mockUserProvider.
    Setup(u => u.CreateUser(new user, ""))
    .Returns(new UserResponseObject { uid = "123", uri = userUri }).Verifiable();
```

from this you need to rectify your verify statement as you are checking that a new user is made:

```
mockUserProvider.Verify(u => u.CreateUser(It.IsAny<User>()));
```

this means that you are actually checking that a user entity is created whereas before you arent testing what you expected the outcome to be. its like testing something along the lines of this - say you are going to create a piece of art you plan it and set it all up (your mock). but you dont yet know what you will create - so in your verify you create the piece of art and need to verify that it is some type of art and not just that the method has run as it returns something which you didnt check.